# Misalignment between two elements of a webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question about why the formatting of my webpage is not working. I am new to Stack Overflow, so please forgive me if my code is not properly formatted.

I am trying to build a webpage with a static menu on the left and a scrolling element in the center. The issue is that after putting the HTML and the CSS together, the static menu aligns properly with the page while the scrolling div in the center is offset down the page a few spaces. Have I entered extra spacing somewhere, or is my code in error?

```css
#profile_followers {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pfollowerstitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 175px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pfollowers {
  width: 175px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#profiles_following {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pfollowingtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 175px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pfollowing {
  width: 175px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#your_posts {
  margin-left: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700px;
  position: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="profile_followers">
    <li class="pfollowerstitle" font-weight="bold"><a href="">Recent followers</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 1</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 2</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <ul id="profiles_following">
    <li class="pfollowingtitle"><a href="">Recently followed</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 1</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 2</a></li>
    <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="your_posts">
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is a photo of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1MPe.jpg

If there are any other formatting issues or places where I can make my code more efficient please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: If you use the development tools in your browser, it will show you what's going on. Right click and do an "inspect" or "inspect element". You need to control the width of the first `div`.

Comment: you've not set any properties on the first <div> element so it is displaying it's default correctly.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your first div a class or ID so that you can manipulate its styling:

```css
        .list-wrap {
          position: relative;
          float: left;
        }

        #profile_followers {
          float: left;
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 5px;
          position: fixed;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .pfollowerstitle {
          font-weight: bold;
          width: 175px;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .pfollowers {
          width: 175px;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        #profiles_following {
          float: left;
          text-decoration: none;
          list-style-type: none;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 5px;
          position: fixed;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .pfollowingtitle {
          font-weight: bold;
          width: 175px;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .pfollowing {
          width: 175px;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        #your_posts {
          margin-left: 200px;
          text-decoration: none;
          background-color: white;
          color: black;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 5px;
          overflow: auto;
          width: 700px;
          position: auto;
        }
```

```html
   <div class="list-wrap">
      <ul id="profile_followers">
        <li class="pfollowerstitle" font-weight="bold"><a href="">Recent followers</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 1</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 2</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowers"><a href="">Recent follower 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    
      <ul id="profiles_following">
        <li class="pfollowingtitle"><a href="">Recently followed</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 1</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 2</a></li>
        <li class="pfollowing"><a href="">Recent followed 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="your_posts">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

main div takes full width and 
 makes the main div move down so many rows and so the misalignment.

It's a multi column layout that you want to build. Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/tbpuL3xa/

say this is your 2 divs:

```
<div id="menu">
</div>
<div id="id_posts">
</div>
```

Now do the following:

- make menu (left div) float so both divs can be on the same row (top alignment).
- set fixed width on menu div and same amount of margin-left on main div so they don't overlap.

```css
#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

#your_posts {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```